# Construction avec souhaiter (souhaiter de+inf)

Tags: grammaire, expressions, prépositions, subjonctif, constructions

J'ai lu sur une carte de remerciements le phrase ci-après :

> Je vous souhaite de passer un très bon week-end.

N'y a-t-il pas une faute ici ?

Ne devrait-elle pas être comme ci-dessous ?

> Je souhaite que vous passiez un très bon week-end.

**Je souhaite passer (sans préposition)** est possible quand le sujet du verbe et l' infinitif est le même (qui n'est pas le cas ici quand même), n'est-ce pas ?

NB : Je n'ai pas cherché tous mes livres de grammaire mais au moins "A French Reference Grammar" (H. Ferrrar) et "A Student Grammar of French" (M. Offold) ne traitent pas de cette construction (à savoir **souhaiter+de**).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les deux constructions existent et sont correctes.

"Je vous souhaite de passer un très bon week-end" fonctionne exactement comme "Je vous souhaite un bon voyage" si ce n'est que l'object du verbe est une proposition infinitive plutôt qu'un groupe nominal. Pas besoin d'une alternance entre l'infinitif et le subjonctif ici parce que l'objet indirect de souhaiter indique déjà qui bénéficie du souhait.

Le *de* qui marque l'infinitif mais pas le groupe nominal est sujet de grand débat dans la linguistique du français, mais n'est probablement pas une préposition. Certaines écoles de pensée y voient un "complémentiseur", c'est à dire une particule qui permette à une proposition de servir de complément du verbe (*que* dans "Je souhaite que vous passiez" est aussi un complémentiseur)

Le pendant nominal de "Je souhaite que vous passiez un très bon week-end" est par contre "Je souhaite un poney", sans complément indirect. Parce que le bénéficiaire de l'action n'est pas marqué sur le verbe principal, l'alternance entre infinitif et subjonctif est nécessaire.

Comment: Excellente réponse. Merci vivement. Mais, pourquoi mes grammaires de référence que j' ai (au moins celles que j'ai consultées:-!) n'en parlent pas ?

Comment: @dimitris Elles auraient dû! Voir par example http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/460c13a.html, qui parle en long et en large du sujet (dans les sections intitulées "subordonant"). C'est une propriété d'un grand nombre de verbes, et pas seulement de *souhaiter*: "Je vous conseille de travailler"="Je conseille que vous travailliez"; "Il m'a proposé de partir plus tôt"="Il a proposé que je parte plus tôt". Pour ce qui est de savoir si un verbe permet ce genre de construction, le mieux est de consulter un dictionnaire. L'entrée de *souhaiter* au TLFi évoque certainement le sujet: .../

Comment: .../ dans sa section intitulée **Souhaiter qqc. à.**, particulièrement les points **α** à **δ** http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/souhaiter